Auto update procedure based on user input
I'm working on some code with a section that remaps certain values based on a scripting dictionary. If an input value isn't already included in the dictionary, then I'll need to ask the user for an override value to map it to.
I'm curious if there's a way to actually update the code to add these inputs into the dictionary itself so that they won't need given again in the future. As an example:
Starting Dictionary:
With dict
    .Add "val1", "Value 1"
    .Add "val2", "Value 2"
End With

The procedure then receives an input of val3, so it asks for input and the user gives Value 3. Is it possible to have the code update so that the next time it runs, the dictionary already has the .Add "val3", "Value 3"?

Store the keys and values on a (hidden) worksheet and read them from there - that will be 100x easier than using VBA to edit your VBA...  You can easily add new keys/values to the existing data.

To elaborate on Tim's point. You can have a double-column Table of these two datapoints, and if there's no match, you run a macro with a msgbox to input these values to populate another row in that table for the formula to pull from.

Normally that's how I would do it if I was running this from a specific workbook, but the code is stored in the Personal workbook as the source workbook for the data always changes. I was able to figure out somewhat of a workaround, creating a function to create the dictionary in a separate module and then calling a separate procedure that updates the code through VBIDE. Only issue is once that finshes I can't enter break mode for debugging. I'll likely use a module-level dictionary object so I can run this at the end of the main procedure.

Why can't you store the data on a sheet in your Personal.xlsm?
